# Getting NullPointerException while getting data from SQLiteDatabase in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using public class DatabaseHandler that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
and this is my method to get all the data from the db, it looks all fine but crashes, and activity says nullpointerException. Is there anything to change in the code? I have only one row of information..

```
// Getting all data

public Cursor getData(String UserName, String Email, String Password,
        String BirthDate, String PinCode, String Country, String PaypalID,
        String mobile, String FBID) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DATA, new String[] { "UserName",
            "Email", "Password", "BirthDate", "PinCode", "Country",
            "PaypalID", "mNUMBER", "FBID" }, null, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor != null) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.i("counttttttttttttt", "" + cursor.getCount());

                UserName = cursor.getString(0);
                Email = cursor.getString(1);
                Password = cursor.getString(2);
                BirthDate = cursor.getString(3);
                PinCode = cursor.getString(4);
                Country = cursor.getString(5);
                PaypalID = cursor.getString(6);
                mobile = cursor.getString(7);
                FBID = cursor.getString(8);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

In, Account Activity,

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(AccountActivity.this);

   // Declared all String

    db.getData(name, email, password, birthdate, pincode, country, paypal,
            mobile, fbid);
```

and set those String to TextView as required..

but it says nullpointer exception.

Comment: if (cursor.getCount !=0) {

      while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                Log.i("counttttttttttttt", "" + cursor.getCount());

                UserName = cursor.getString(0);
                Email = cursor.getString(1);
                Password = cursor.getString(2);
                BirthDate = cursor.getString(3);
                PinCode = cursor.getString(4);
                Country = cursor.getString(5);
                PaypalID = cursor.getString(6);
                mobile = cursor.getString(7);
                FBID = cursor.getString(8);

            } 
        }
    }

Comment: @Vinayak Nonsense. `while(cursor.moveToNext())` is enough. No need count, no need if/do/while like OP.

Comment: : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: Process: com.vinnig.loginandplay, PID: 1022
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vinnig.loginandplay/com.vinnig.pages.AccountActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 07:36:25.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-11 07:36:25.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

Comment: its not duplicate, it has different issue

Comment: Thanks, Vinayak.. but still the same error, as logcat above..

Comment: There are problems in the code you posted but not necessarily anything to do with the NPE (for example, the `getData()` doesn't do anything useful as the retrieved data is thrown away). Start by editing the post and posting the full exception stacktrace (including the nested NPE itself).

Comment: ok, how to post full exception stacktrace.. because it does not let me post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brothers, I found that the method to getData is all wrong..
The Right Method is..

```
// Getting all data
public Cursor getData() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DATA, new String[] { "UserName",
            "Email", "Password", "BirthDate", "PinCode", "Country",
            "PaypalID", "mNUMBER", "FBID" }, null, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    return cursor;
}
```

means No parameters in a method, like i did before, because we are not adding or updating any fields, so no need for that in case of fetching data..

And in Activity,

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(AccountActivity.this);

    // getAllData();
    Cursor cursor = db.getData();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.i("counttttttttttttt", "" + cursor.getCount());

            name = cursor.getString(0);
            email = cursor.getString(1);
            password = cursor.getString(2);
            birthdate = cursor.getString(3);
            pincode = cursor.getString(4);
            country = cursor.getString(5);
            paypal = cursor.getString(6);
            mobile = cursor.getString(7);
            fbid = cursor.getString(8);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
db.close;
```

name, email, password are Strings inside and you can set it respectively.. 
Thanks for your help..

Answer (score -1):

```
            if( cursor !=null && cursor.getCount() != 0)
        {
            while( cursor.moveToNext() )
            {
                UserName = cursor.getString(0);
                Email = cursor.getString(1);
                Password = cursor.getString(2);
                BirthDate = cursor.getString(3);
                PinCode = cursor.getString(4);
                Country = cursor.getString(5);
                PaypalID = cursor.getString(6);
                mobile = cursor.getString(7);
                FBID = cursor.getString(8);
                //add data to a list
            }
        }
```